# Problema ao remover todos os atributos de um objeto que contém valores nulos

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, recursão

### Contexto

Eu estou dentro de uma aplicação em NodeJS, onde eu tenho um objeto bem grande que possui vários atributos e também atributos objetos que possuem filhos, e eu tenho uma situação onde eu não posso manter os atributos que contém valores nulos, por isso eu fiz uma função para remover os atributos que contem valores nulos, mas acabou que alguns objetos tinham todos os atributos nulos, e ai isso gerou outro problema, porque não posso manter um objeto que não tenha nenhum filho.

### Objetivo

Preciso remover os atributos que forem objetos e não possuírem mais filhos logo após a minha varredura que remove todos os atributos que contém valores nulos.

### Código

```js
var objMapped = {
a: true,
b: false,
c: null,
d: undefined,
e: 10,
temFilhos: {
 nullAttr: null,
  nullAttr2: null,
  nullAttr3: null
}
};
console.log('antes', objMapped);
 //isso remove atributos de objeto que tem valores nulos, recursivamente percorrendo os objetos que tem filhos tambem
    const removeEmptyAttrs = (objMapped) => {
      Object.keys(objMapped).forEach(key => {
        if (objMapped[key] && typeof objMapped[key] === 'object') removeEmptyAttrs(objMapped[key]);
        else if (objMapped[key] === null) delete objMapped[key];
      });
    };
    
removeEmptyAttrs(objMapped);
console.log('depois', objMapped);
```

Note que no código acima eu acabo por obter um objeto `temFilhos` que na verdade já não tem mais nenhum filho, por isso não é correto manter ele vivo, gostaria que o meu código também removesse o pai se caso ele não tiver mais filhos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não basta um `if` com o respetivo `delete` no sitio certo ? No caso o `if` tem de verificar a quantidade de chaves que o objeto fica a após a recursão, e se ficar com `0` remove o pai.

Exemplo:

```js
var objMapped = {
a: true,
b: false,
c: null,
d: undefined,
e: 10,
temFilhos: {
 nullAttr: null,
  nullAttr2: null,
  nullAttr3: null
}
};
console.log('antes', objMapped);

const removeEmptyAttrs = (objMapped) => {
  Object.keys(objMapped).forEach(key => {
    if (objMapped[key] && typeof objMapped[key] === 'object'){
      removeEmptyAttrs(objMapped[key]);
      if (Object.keys(objMapped[key]).length === 0){ //se pai ficou sem filhos
        delete objMapped[key]; //remove pai
      }
    }
    else if (objMapped[key] === null) delete objMapped[key];
  });
};
    
removeEmptyAttrs(objMapped);
console.log('depois', objMapped);
```

Comment: como que eu não pensei nisso mano? tava na minha cara kkkkkkkkkk aquela vontade de morrer básica.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Estamos cá para ajudar :)